# Send notifications to group of users

Tags: android, kotlin, onesignal

I have android app that includes sections. After user login he can follow a section. Inside every section users can add posts. I want when someone posts something on specific section. All followers gets notification of the post. Like what happens on Facebook groups.

I'm using OneSignal. Should I use tags? Also, I see when user clears the cache and re-login to the app. All connected tags are lost. He will not get notifications until he unfollow the section and then re-follow it again. So OneSignal.sendTags get triggered again.

What are the best solution here?

Comment: What back-end service are you using?

Comment: @Christilyn PHP with laravel framework

Comment: @Christilyn Sorry I thought you asked about the backend of the app. I'm using one signal as I mentioned in my question above.

Comment: It may be the case that the token is refreshed whenever you clear the local cache. So you would have to retrieve it again to get you a new token. One way to handle this is to just store a list of user's subscriptions in your user table. So whenever your user's token updates, you still keep track of his/her subscriptions and they will not have to re-subscribe

Comment: @Christilyn Thanks, I already did that. I also I have every user token in users table. I just need a better way instead of looping on every user following this section and get his token then send the notification -> wait for the respoonse then go for the next one. I think there is a better way. Also, I'm using php and in php any request need to wait for the response to go for the next one. So If I have just 10 or 20 users following a section to send a notification it could take 2 to 3 minutes or something just for the user who added the post to get response from the backend.

Comment: Have you tried setting up segments and sending notifications from there? https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/segmentation

Comment: @Christilyn Thanks The link you sent helped. It has useful videos I didn't come through it before.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you can use a firebase solution or you can go with rabbit mq or any other messaging services , so you need to save all the devices token in you users table , and the when you trigger your function you send the notification to all the tokens of the members 
you want to notify , this technique is working fine

Comment: Thanks, My app already have chat service I save users token in the users table. But I thought their could be better solution to send notification one time to all followers. Instead of looping through every user and send notification one by one.

Comment: then you can use your chat service to notify all the users inside the channel , it depends on your chat back end